# How can I make text appear in front of a box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running some basic GUI code within Python, using TkInter:

```
# Making a blank canvas to "draw" on, it can easily be seen as it will be white
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, background="white")
canvas.grid(row=6, column=5)

# Creating text to go within the boxes
officeText = canvas.create_text(125, 110, text="Office")

# Creating boxes within the canvas
officeGraphic = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150, fill="orange")
```

However the problem that I am having is that the text "office" is appearing behind the orange box. How can I bring this text to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TK will draw widgets in the order they're created, with the widgets created last on top of the widgets created before it. Using that logic, you can simply move `officeText` down:

```
# Creating boxes within the canvas
officeGraphic = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150, fill="orange")

# Creating text to go within the boxes
officeText = canvas.create_text(125, 110, text="Office")
```

Answer (score 2):

If changing the order of creation is not an option, you can use the cavas' [`tag_raise`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_raise-method) method.

```
canvas.tag_raise(officeText)
```